# Deleting 2d slice from 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have got a 3d np.array with shape looking like this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([112, 200, 200])
indexes = [0, 1, 110, 111]
```

With `arr.shape: (112, 200, 200)` and a list of indexes: `indexes = [0, 1, 111, 111]`. What I want is to get rid of the slices of `(200, 200)` with indexes from the list, so that the final shape would look like this: `arr.shape: (108, 200, 200)`. I tried with deleting `arr[index,:,:]` but can't actually use that to delete those slices.

Comment: Sine you want to omit the first two and last two ''planes' you can just slice `arr1 = arr[2:-2, :, :]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) to remove specific elements from an array. In this case you can pass it the indices and `axis=0`

Note: index 112 is not in your array since arrays are zero-indexed. I changed it to 111 to avoid the warning:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([112, 200, 200])
indexes = [0, 1, 110, 111]

b = np.delete(a, indexes, axis=0)
b.shape
# (108, 200, 200)
```